# Unable to print device variable value within kernel in CUDA

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I am trying to understand how pointers function in CUDA.

Given below is a simple program which assigns certain value to a variable allocated in the device. 
(I'm using CUDA toolkit 8.0 with NVIDIA Quadro K2000 Graphics card)

When I print the value within the kernel using printf(), it displays a wrong value.

However, when I do a cudaMemcopy from host function and then print from the host function, it displays the correct value...

```
//CODE...
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<cuda.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>
#define N 3

__global__ void tempker(int *jk,int value)
{
    (*jk) = value*2;
    printf("displayed from inside the kernel :\nvalue of jk = %d\nvalue of *jk = %d\n",jk,*jk);

}
int tempfunc(int *kp)
{
    int *jk = NULL,*lm=NULL;
    lm = (int *)(malloc(sizeof(int)));
    *lm = 150;
    cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&jk, sizeof(int));
    printf("jk pointer after cudaMalloc: displayed from host = %d\n",jk);
    tempker<<<1,1>>>(jk,150);
    err = cudaGetLastError();//brief Returns the last error from a runtime call
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    err = cudaMemcpy(lm, jk, (sizeof(int)), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy jk from device to host (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Displayed in host function after memcopy: value of *lm = *jk = %d\n",*lm);
    cudaFree(jk);
    err = cudaMalloc((void**)&kp, sizeof(int));
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device kp (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    tempker<<<1,1>>>(kp,(N*N*N));
    err = cudaGetLastError();//brief Returns the last error from a runtime call
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    err = cudaMemcpy(lm, kp, (sizeof(int)), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy kp from device to host (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Displayed in host function after memcopy: value of *lm = *kp = %d\n",*lm);
    cudaFree(kp);
    free(lm);
    return 100;
}

int main(){

    int *kp = NULL;
    printf("tempfunc(): return value = %d\n",tempfunc(kp));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
jk pointer after cudaMalloc: displayed from host = 13238272
displayed from inside the kernel :
value of jk = 13238272
value of *jk = 9
Displayed in host function after memcopy: value of *lm = *jk = 300
displayed from inside the kernel :
value of jk = 13238272
value of *jk = 9
Displayed in host function after memcopy: value of *lm = *kp = 54
tempfunc(): return value = 100
```

The Question is: 
**Is it possible to print value of a variable allocated in device within the kernel?**

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your code *is* printing out the value of a device variable within a kernel. What makes you think it is not?

Comment: It is printing wrong value however, for example, when kernel is launched first, *jk should be = 150 * 2 = 300. But within the kernel, it prints '9'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying integer value with *"%d"* is considered correct.
Displaying address with *"%d"* might lead to unpredictable behaviour depending on your compiler.

Simply use *"%p"*. As it expects a void pointer, explicitely cast your pointer.

So in your kernel :

```
printf("value = %d, address = %p\n",*jk,(void *)jk);
```

More info is available if you look further into [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: Great... When i changed %d with %p for the pointer, it's printing the correct value from the kernel... (as you said, the %d used for displaying address was leading to unpredictable behavior which displayed wrong results (the 9 instead of 300 and 54)...) Now this code is printing correct values within kernel (300, the first time and 54, the second time within the kernel)....Thanks...

Comment: Glad I could help. :)